# Depite command exit task does not end in Devops Pipelines in container pipeline

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a command line task on a Windows Container pipeline on Azure Devops. That despite the last line fired of the script was.

```
EXIT /B 1
```

and the log result was

```
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
```

The task would not end and simply run until the default timeout of 60 minutes (that can be changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the bat file launched a daemon previously in the script. In my case it was running a Gradle build. Gradle automatically launches a daemon to speed up any subsequent builds. It seems if the bat script launched by a cmd task in Azure Pipelines on a Containerized job launches a background service, the task will not end.

The solution for Gradle is to include the following line in your script before running the build

```
set GRADLE_OPTS=%GRADLE_OPTS% -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could Accept it as an Answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT should this be reported as a bug on Azure Devops? The non-containerized build pipeline handles this just fine, but the docker does not. The task *should* end since the script ends and returns an ERROR_LEVEL, the background tasks would die when the container is killed anyway. And if my pipeline was building more Gradle builds it would be useful.